# Error with "Collapsed inline menu" by Ant Design

Tags: reactjs

I am new to the world of react and javascript.
I encounter quite a mistake with the Ant Design code for the collapsed inline menu.
I tried several solutions found on the forum but without success.

And I do not quite understand the notion of one of the errors that is "Must Use destructuring state assignment"

I stick you my code and the errors that are indicated to me.

for the error "Missing Parentheses around multilines JSX" I have already tried the mettres but I have another error that appears.

when I click on the button nothing happens

I hope you can help me.

thank you in advance

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Menu, Icon, Button } from 'antd';

const { SubMenu } = Menu;

class RightVerticalMenu extends Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: false,
  };

  toggleCollapsed = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { collapsed } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="right-menu" style={{ width: 256 }}>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={this.toggleCollapsed}
          style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}
        >
          <Icon type={this.toggleCollapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'} />
        </Button>
        <Menu
          defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
          defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
          mode="inline"
          theme="dark"
          inlineCollapsed={collapsed}
        >
          <SubMenu
            key="sub1"
            title={
              <span>
                <Icon type="mail" />
                <span>Métérologie</span>
              </span>
            }
          >
            <Menu.Item key="5">Option 5</Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>

          <SubMenu
            key="sub2"
            title={
              <span>
                <Icon type="appstore" />
                <span>Chat</span>
              </span>
            }
          >
            <Menu.Item key="9">Option 9</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="10">Option 10</Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RightVerticalMenu;
```

console errors :

```
Must Use destructuring state assignment[29, 19]
Missing Parentheses around multilines JSX[55, 15] and [67, 15]
```

Comment: Are you sure that this errors are for this component?. You are using some eslint-config, which has predefined rules and showing this as errors.  This code doesnt have  67 lines but as you can see [67, 15] at the end.  I assume these errors are from different page, in console can u verify file name on top of these errors.... And this code working fine when i click on button it is folding and unfolding menu  https://codesandbox.io/s/y084pw6jpx

Comment: and forgot to mention use <Icon type={collapsed ? "menu-unfold" : "menu-fold"} />  ..

Comment: is that working for you? If not, then find eslintrc file in your project folder and comment the entire file. If there is no eslintrc file then in package.json there may be extends key just remove it { extends : "XXXXX"}. And then restart your react app (should kill and start again).

Comment: thank you so much for your return Hemanthvrm. 
Indeed, my ESlint sends me errors, I will do the procedures that you propose me.

However, what does using two frameworks (semantic-ui and ants) also can not cause this bug ?

Because I believe that the ANTS css does not apply

Comment: perfect Hemanthvrm . it's ok for me. I comment the entire file (eslintrc).